# Data insertion using auto incremented column as primary key

Tags: java, sql, foreign-keys, auto-increment, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables whereby the primary key(foreign key on the other table) is auto incremented at run time (using TOAD for mysql).
How can I insert data into the two tables at the same time using a transaction.

This is the ddl for the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE `suspendedsales` (
`SID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SequenceNo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`ProductCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`ItemName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`Quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`Discount` double DEFAULT NULL,
`ItemCost` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`SID`,`SequenceNo`),
CONSTRAINT `SIDFKey` FOREIGN KEY (`SID`) REFERENCES `suspendedsalesdetails` (`SID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The ddl for the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `suspendedsalesdetails` (
`SID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Total` double DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`SID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

N.B: The major challenge would be to get the auto-incremented key value from on the primary key to be inserted into the other table at run time.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: i would say you first turn off the auto commit from toad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is a MySql database you can insert a record in the first table use the following function

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

to get the last inserted id and you can use it in the second insert. Commit all only after the second insert

Comment: Sometimes a simple answer is just the right one. i initially didn't consider your answer and wasted a lot of time trying to adjust the prior code. Thanks a million. You just saved me.  NB: for anybody having this same challenge just use the last_insert_Id as your value in prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 private void insert() {

    OraclePreparedStatement statement = null;


    try {
        Connection dbConnection = getConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement(); 

        String insertToSuspendedsales  = "insert into suspendedsales (SequenceNo, ProductCode,ItemName,Quantity,Discount,ItemCost) "
            + "values(:segNo, :prodNo, :itmeName, :quantity, :discount, :itemCost) returning SID into ?";

        statement.setIntAtName("segNo", intValue);
        ....

        int id =  statement.registerReturnParameter(1, OracleTypes.INTEGER)
        statement.executeUpdate(insertToSuspendedsales);

        String insertToSuspendedsalesdetails = "insert into suspendedsalesdetails (SID, Date, Total) "
            + "values(:sid, :date, :total) returning SID into ?";


        statement.setIntAtName("sid", id);
        .... 

        statement.executeUpdate(insertToSuspendedsalesdetails);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //rollback
    } finally {

      //close Connection
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems a good code. Could you reproduce this using mysql data base and prepared Statements?